# Last.fm scrobbling on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, last.fm-client

Does the default Music app on Ubuntu Touch support (realtime) Last.fm scrobbling?

Answer (score 0):

According to the developers there is no support for Last.fm/Libre.fm scrobbling implemented at the moment, but they seem to be positive for the future: https://answers.launchpad.net/music-app/+question/269528